# Audio on each touch in meteor

Tags: cordova, audio, meteor, mobile

I am building a chatApp very similar to whatsapp.
I want to highlight the text on click and also play a click sound for better user experience. I am capturing the touch events by 'touchstart', and 'touchend' and changing the UI using that. 
Now I also want to add sound on touch event. I want the default mobile sound to be played on click.

Any insights..??

Comment: Did you actually researched some libraries?

Comment: Rocket.chat already use this sound feature, so I recommend go through it